# Why must json_encode appear in php file and not in an external javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a php array:

```
$x = array("1","2","3");
```

I also have javascript code to convert the php array into a javascript array:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>;
```

It works perfectly when I type this out in the index.php file (ie - I can use that array in any other javascript file):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var x = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>; </script>
```

But it doesn't work when I do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file.js"></script>
```

And file.js contains:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>;
```

I just can't understand why this is the case, any idea why? Thanks in advance.

Comment: .js files cannot process PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External JS files are not PHP files. They will NOT be parsed by PHP parser (web server).

To "enable" PHP tags in external JS files, you can name it with `script.js.php` (ends with `.php`), and the example contents are as follow:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
?>
var x = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>;
```

and import it with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js.php"></script>
```

---

Apart from using the above method, here is another way to "merge" JS and PHP, in a tricky way:

Contents in an external PHP file (assume the file name is `method2.inc.php`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>;
</script>
```

Instead of using `<script>` tag to include it into original PHP file, you use:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Method 2</title>
<?php require_once('method2.inc.php'); ?>
</head>
<body>
<-- body goes here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Note: The filename is free to change, as long as its file extension is `.php`.

Comment: Is necessary to call `.js` ? Or just for info ?

Comment: @Don what do you mean?

Comment: I just tried it but the javascript code isn't getting parsed, it simply returns text.

Comment: How & where did you load the file?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I mean that if I name the file `script.php`, will work or not ?

Comment: It will work. adding `.js` just reminds developers the file contains JavaScript.

Comment: I loaded the file after the php code, following exactly what you typed. The variable returns null.

Comment: Could it be because the php variable '$x' is not declared in 'script.js.php'?

Comment: Certainly. Of course you have to have complete logic in the external JS/PHP file.

Comment: Going to break lots of things if I transfer the php over, is there by any chance a way to get that array over?

Comment: there is an invention called AJAX. You'll need that.

Comment: Also updated the answer to provide alternative solution, in case you need it.

Answer (score 0):

> I just can't understand why this is the case, any idea why?

Because your server does not send files with ending `.js` through the PHP parser by default …

You can f.e. name the file `.php` instead, then it will be parsed. But be aware that you’ll have to send the appropriate Content-Type header yourself in that case:

```
header('Content-Type: …');
```